# Join in exam oca 051

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I see a question in oracle certifications.

You want to list all cities that have more than one customer along with the customer details.
Evaluate the following query:

```
SQL>SELECT c1.custname, c1.city
FROM Customers c1 __________________ Customers c2
ON (c1.city=c2.city AND c1.custname<>c2.custname);
```

Which two 'JOIN' options can be used in the blank in the above query to give the correct output? (Choose two.)

A.'JOIN'

B.'NATURAL JOIN'

C.'LEFT OUTER JOIN'

D.'FULL OUTER JOIN'

E.'RIGHT OUTER JOIN'

Answers: A, E

I don't know why he added c1.custname<>c2.custname to 'on' section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without c1.custname<>c2.custname this query would result in listing all the clients and cities, not only the ones with more than one customer

```
 custname | city
 Smith    |  NY
 Thompson |  LA
 Locke    |  LA
```

Without the clause it would return all customers because when we join Smith | NY with Smith | NY on cities only we get a match - with aditional c1.custname<>c2.custname this is not possible, because o the same name